# Error Writing Data To Text File

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using access to write data to a text file, but I get this error

> invalid procedure call or argument

What do I need to alter in this procedure so that data can be succesfully written?  I have access to the path, and the file already exists and is spelled properly in my code.

```
 Function WriteData(fulllocale As String, tblName As String, CString As String)
  Dim fso As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim Fileout As Object
  Set Fileout = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", ForAppending, True)
  Fileout.Write fulllocale & "," & tblName & "," & CString & vbCrLf
  Fileout.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForAppending` isn't declared, and since you've apparently late bound your `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, it's getting initialized to a local `Variant` with it's default value.

You can prevent this in the future by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules.

Either add the reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (there is absolutely no reason not to), or use the integer value of the `IOMode`.  In this case, `ForAppending`, which is 8:

```
Set Fileout = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", 8, True)
```

Comment: This removes the error but writes garbage to my text file.  Like "㩃呜獥屴捁潣湵楴杮愮"  I need it in English-USA